# What does $\sum_{m=1}^n \ln (1 -\frac{\theta^2}{n}+ \frac{\theta^2}{2n m(\log m)^2} )$ converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

What does the following sum converge to as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

$$\sum_{m=2}^n \ln (1 -\frac{\theta^2}{n}+ \frac{\theta^2}{2n m(\log m)^2} )$$

I think it converges to $-\theta^2/2$, but I am not sure how to show this?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{m=2}^{n}\ln\left(1-\frac{\theta^2}{n}+\frac{\theta^2}{2nm\ln^2m}\right)=-\frac{\theta^2}{n}\sum_{m=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2m\ln^2m}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ and, since $\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac{1}{m\ln^2m}$ converges, the given sum converges to $-\theta^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do you know what $\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac{1}{m\ln^2m}$ converges to?

Comment: It doesn't matter *what* it converges *to*, since it gets divided by $n$, and the result tends to $0$ with $n\to\infty$. (The convergence itself is shown using e.g. the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). The actual value may be related to $\zeta$-function somehow.)